# Maven build fails on Ubuntu 12.04, JDK1.7

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, java-7

My maven build is fine on Windows machine but fails with compilation error on Ubuntu.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project [XXX]: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/share/tomcat7/[XXX]:[24,23] error: no suitable constructor found for XXX
[ERROR]
[ERROR] constructor XXX is not applicable
[ERROR] (actual argument Class<XXX> cannot be converted to Class<? extends XXX> by method invocation conversion)
[ERROR] constructor XXX is not applicable
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR] /usr/share/tomcat7/[XXX]:[36,24] error: no suitable constructor found for XXX)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
```

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-46-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

I already tried building it on java 1.6 and changing java to oracle-7-JDK...

Error stays the same.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

I have installed Oracle JDK according to [provided instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Now it looks like this:

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-46-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Build still fails with the same error message

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is the Java version. I am not quite sure you have the fully fledged Java JDK. Can you please install the Java JDK [instructions here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) and see if the error persists?

Comment: Thanks for instructions. I'll try that and get back to you...

Comment: Check the messages `/usr/share/tomcat7/[XXX]:[24,23] error: no suitable constructor found for XXX
[ERROR]
[ERROR] constructor XXX is not applicable` there is your problem.

Comment: Try running with -dmaven.compiler.verbose=true for additional infos. Also, please show us the Constructor of XXX as well as your actual call. What happens if you try to compile the code by hand (javac)?

Comment: What is class XXX, is it your class?

Answer (score 0):

Update your pom file to use an up-to-date maven-compiler-plugin version (you are using 2.0.2 extremly old).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: This was just a hint to update your compiler plugin version it will clean your errors you have with your code.